# C++: How to create a "conditional" constructor/avoid destruct on assignment?

Tags: c++

Let's start with some example code:

```cpp
class Shader {
public:

    static absl::StatusOr<Shader> Create(const std::string &vertexShaderFile, const std::string &fragmentShaderFile) {
        ASSIGN_OR_RETURN(GLuint vertexShader, gl::createShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, readFile(vertexShaderFile)))
        ASSIGN_OR_RETURN(GLuint fragmentShader, gl::createShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, readFile(fragmentShaderFile)))

        Shader s;
        glAttachShader(s._programId, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(s._programId, fragmentShader);
        RETURN_IF_ERROR(gl::linkProgram(s._programId));
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

        std::cerr << "AAA" << std::endl;
        return s;
    }

    void use() const {
        std::cerr << "use " << _programId << std::endl;
        glUseProgram(_programId);
    }

    ~Shader() {
        std::cerr << "destruct!" << std::endl;
        glDeleteProgram(_programId);
    }

private:
    explicit Shader() : _programId(glCreateProgram()) {}
    GLuint _programId{0};
};
```

usage:

```cpp
const auto &_statusOr4 = (Shader::Create("resources/vertex.glsl", "resources/frag.glsl"));
if (!_statusOr4.ok())return _statusOr4.status();
Shader shader = *_statusOr4;

std::cerr << "BBB" << std::endl;
```

This will print:

```
AAA
destruct!
BBB
```

I think the `s` in `Shader::Create` is being *copied* to a new object and then the old one is destructed, which calls the `~Shader` destructor.

I want to avoid the copy + destruct.

I can't just throw all the `Create` code in the c'tor because there's a few operations that might fail.

How can I do this?

---

Adding

```cpp
    Shader(const Shader&) = delete;
    Shader& operator=(const Shader&) = delete;
```

Prevents this program from compiling. Which is fine, because this is indeed an error, but then I still don't know how to write such a `Create` method (without moving everything into a constructor and throwing exceptions instead)

---

I tried to add a [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

```cpp
    Shader(Shader&& o) noexcept : _programId(o._programId){
        std::cerr << "move ctor" << std::endl;
    }
```

Had to change the assignment to make it a reference:

```
const auto &_statusOr4 = (Shader::Create("resources/vertex.glsl", "resources/frag.glsl"));
if (!_statusOr4.ok()) return _statusOr4.status();
const Shader& shader = *_statusOr4;
```

Which I think should be fine because `_statusOr4` will have the same lifetime.

However.... now I get

```
AAA
move ctor
destruct!
BBB
```

It seems the destructor is still called on the object that it was "moved" out of.

---

`StatusOr` is [from Abseil](https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/status#overview-of-abslstatus)

Comment: @Raildex There shouldn't be an implicit default c'tor if there's an explicit one I thought? AFAICT it's trying to use the copy constructor.

Comment: The GL program object that is created with `glCreateProgram` is a typical resource such as memory that is allocated or a file descriptor. You cannot place it in an object that is freely copyable. You have to make the object move-only, and you have to have a particular value that lets you know whether the resource has already been released or not. Otherwise, you get double-releases left and right.

Comment: @j6t Right. I deleted the copy and assignment c'tors after writing that, but I don't know how to make it move-only. Putting `return std::move(s)` didn't really change anything.

Comment: You need to write a correct move constructor (and probably a move assignment operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to avoid the copy + destruct.

Normally, when your function return type matches the type of the variable you return, you don't need to do anything. There is no copying and no destruction taking place. Read about [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

In your case, you construct `Shader` but return `absl::StatusOr<Shader>`. So there are two different objects: the local variable `s` in your function, and the return value. They are of different types so the compiler cannot make them the same thing, and you will see the destructor of `s` being called. However this is harmless if you write `Shader` correctly. Support [move construction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), and `s` will be moved to the return value, leaving behind an empty shell that is trivial to destroy. There is still [no copying](https://godbolt.org/z/vEYaazc5o).

Assuming that 0 is an invalid/empty shader program and `glDeleteProgram(0)` is essentially a no-op, the move constructor could look like this:

```
Shader(Shader&& other) {
   _programId = other._programId;
   other._programId = 0;
}
```

You don't want to freely copy objects `Shader` objects, because otherwise you will end up deleting the same  `_programId` more than once. To avoid this, mark the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator as `delete`.

> I can't just throw all the Create code in the c'tor because there's a few operations that might fail.

That's what exceptions are for.

Comment: Why do I see a call to `destruct!` then? I unrolled the macro.. maybe that will make it more clear.

Comment: Edited the answer with more info.

Comment: I added a move constructor, but it seems to destructor is still called on the "old" object. Oh... I mean I guess I could write a guard around `glDeleteProgram` but that's kind of lame that I have to track the state myself.

Comment: You're right. Setting it to 0 seems to work.

Comment: The example move constructor can be written more concisely as `Shader(Shader &&other) : _programId(std::exchange(other._programId, 0)) {}`